# Webstorm не подсвечивает файлы с ошибками в левом меню

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

В левом меню, где отображаются файлы, те файлы в которых есть ошибки, не выделяются цветом сразу.
Происходит это только после того, как в этот файл перейти. Тогда он начинает подсвечиваться серым цветом и говорит что в нем допущена ошибка.

Т.е. если я заранее не знаю что в этом файле ошибка, Webstorm мне об этом не сообщит. (ну только если я открою этот файл по нелепой случайности)

В документации так ничего и не удалось найти

Можно ли сделать так, чтоб если в файле ошибка, он сразу подсвечивался, а не ждал пока я в него перейду?

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя, у webstorm нет статического анализатора, поэтому нельзя проверить файл, не открыв его

Comment: И какая связь?..